# MySQL select unique values based on one or more possible clauses

Tags: php, mysql

So there is this database table:

[image: database table]

and this array with selected options:

```
$options[1] = 1;
$options[2] = 5;
$options[3] = 3;
$options[4] = 2;
$options[5] = 1;
...
$options[x] = y;
```

Now, the aim is to fetch all item_ids, where if there is an option_id in its row from one of the options array's keys, the value must be the same as the value in the options array.

For example:

> option 1 has selected value 1
>
> option 2 has selected value 5
>
> option 3 has selected value 4
>
> option 4 has selected value 2

so we should select item_id 1 and other item_ids, where if option 1 -> option 1 = 1 AND if option 2 -> option 2 = 5 AND if option 3 -> option 3 = 4 AND ...

The `item_ids` will be used in IN() to select the items data from the items table.

The main point is that the user selects some options on a page, then the options are put into array, then I must find all items that comply with the selected options. In the table above we have the relation between the items and the options, and the option values per item which are predefined.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you just need to use `DISTINCT`, ie `SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM ...`

Comment: Not really, I need to find all rows that comply with one or more selected option values IF the row has that option id. The `DISTINCT` will also be used, but how can I make the select comply with one or more where clauses? I tried using `IF( option_id = 1, option_value, 'xxx' ) = 1` but when I put more IFs with ANDs, nothing is selected.

Comment: Is `option_value` a foreign key or is that the actual value?

Comment: `option_value` is the actual value. It should be equal to the value of the corresponding array row `$options[id] = value`

Answer (score 0):

```
$where = array();
foreach($options as $key => $value) $where[] = 'option_id = ' . $key . ' AND option_value = ' . $value;
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT item_id
        FROM table
        WHERE (' . explode(') OR (', $where) . ')';
```

I might have completely misunderstood your question however.

Comment: Thanks but this will select the first item for `option_id=1 option_value=1` and `option_id=4 option_value=1000`. I need a rule to comply with all options for an item simultaniously.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do it for you. Haven't tested it at all and it'll probably blow up, but...

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE (item_id in (
    SELECT item_id
    FROM optiontable
    WHERE ((option_id = 1) and (option_value = 1)) or
        ((option_id = 2) and (option_value=5)) or
        ((option_id = 3) and (option_value=3)) or
        ((option_id = 4) and (option_value=2)) or
        ((option_id = 5) and (option_value=1))
    GROUP BY CONCAT(option_id, ',', option_value)
    HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(option_id, ',', option_value)) = 5
));
```

Basically, the inner query pulls out all the rows that match one of the member rows in your required options row. It does an artificial grouping/count on the paired option_id/option_value pairs and returns the item_ids of the rows where the number of opt_id/opt_val pairs add up to 5 rows.

You'd have to build such a query dynamically in the client, so that the number of 'where' clause entries matches the number in the `having` clause.

Comment: Thank you. I get empty result trying to fetch the first item using its options: `SELECT * FROM products_options
WHERE ((option_id = 1) and (option_value = 1)) or
        ((option_id = 4) and (option_value=2))
    GROUP BY CONCAT(option_id, ',', option_value)
    HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(option_id, ',', option_value)) = 2`

Comment: And another thing is that one item can have 2 `option_id/option_value` pairs and another item can have 5 pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$options = array(
    1 => 1,
    2 => 5,
    3 => 3,
    4 => 2,
    5 => 1
);
$cases = array();
foreach($options as $id => $value){
    $cases[] = "WHEN $id THEN $value";
}

$query =
'SELECT item_id '.
'FROM your_table '.
'WHERE option_value = CASE option_id '.implode(' ', $cases).' '.
'GROUP BY item_id';

echo $query;
?>
```

Output (formatted by me):

```sql
  SELECT item_id 
    FROM your_table 
   WHERE option_value = CASE option_id 
            WHEN 1 THEN 1 
            WHEN 2 THEN 5 
            WHEN 3 THEN 3 
            WHEN 4 THEN 2 
            WHEN 5 THEN 1 
GROUP BY item_id
```

Test this query and let me know if it works the way you expect it to. :)

---

#### Update: Suggestion for your final query

```
$query =
'SELECT * FROM items '.
'WHERE id IN('.
'SELECT item_id '.
'FROM your_table '.
'WHERE option_value = CASE option_id '.implode(' ', $cases).' '.
'GROUP BY item_id)';
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I have tried this approach, but I need to include all rules for an item. This way, if an item has `option_id=1 option_value=1` and `option_id=4 option_value=4` will still be selected, but it shouldn't. Only items that have all possible matching combinations of options should be selected.